# How to manually remove an item from List in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I try to remove some item from List but get an error `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range`. I know about `onDelete` but on macOS it's not clear how to call it with mouse

```swift
    @State var wishList = [
        "Item 1",
        "Item 2"
    ]

List {
    ForEach(wishList.indices) { index in
        Button(action: {

        }) {
            HStack {
                Text(self.wishList[index]) //Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range. 
                Button(action: {
                    RunLoop.main.perform {
                        self.wishList.remove(at: index)
                    }
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "minus.circle").foregroundColor(.red)
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Fix:**
I added `id:\.self` to fix my code.

```swift
    @State var wishList = [
        "Item 1",
        "Item 2"
    ]

List {
    ForEach(wishList.indices, id:\.self) { index in
        Button(action: {

        }) {
            HStack {
                Text(self.wishList[index]) //Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range. 
                Button(action: {
                    RunLoop.main.perform {
                        self.wishList.remove(at: index)
                    }
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "minus.circle").foregroundColor(.red)
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause is given to you in an error:

> count (1) != its initial count (2). `ForEach(_:content:)` should only be used for *constant* data. Instead conform data to `Identifiable` or use `ForEach(_:id:content:)` and provide an explicit `id`!

Instead, use an `Identifiable` version and operate directly on the content:

```
    List {
        ForEach(wishList, id: \.self) { content in
            HStack {
                Text(verbatim: content)

                Button(action: {
                    guard let index = self.wishList.firstIndex(of: content) else { return }
                    self.wishList.remove(at: index)
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "minus.circle").foregroundColor(.red)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Here's a simpler version:

```
    List(0..<wishList.count, id: \.self) { index in
        HStack {
            Text(verbatim: self.wishList[index])

            Button(action: {
                self.wishList.remove(at: index)
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "minus.circle").foregroundColor(.red)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I see to fix my code I need to add `id:\.self` into `ForEach`. I added fixed code in my post.

Comment: Thanks, you post helped me find the right solution.